# Could electrical induction cause gross thermocouple errors over time?

Tags: capacitor, capacitance, inductance, error, thermocouple

Before stating the problem let me point out a few the soon to be obvious.

1. I am not an electrical engineer, please do not mistake me for one.  I can wire a house, I know the difference between NPN and PNP, but thats really about it.
2. This question involves brewing but there is no way I'm getting a satisfactory answer to my question on the home brewing forum. Please do not move me there.

I have a chest freezer which I have been using as a keggerator for multiple kegs without issue for about a year. In order to maintain beer storage temperatures I replaced the controller and bi-metal strip with a Red Lion digital temperature controller, SSR, and a thermocouple.  Absolutely no issue for over a year after tuning the controller.  Suddenly two days ago, after moving the unit I noticed my beer line was frozen.  The temperature was down to 18F.  I pressed a  button which puts it in manual mode to keep the compressor off until I had a chance to work on it. When I pulled the cover tonight the temperature was reading 178F. I knew that wasn't right.  The first thing I noticed is that my thermocouple wires were resting on the starting capacitor.  As soon as I moved them the temperature went back to 64F (A pretty reasonable value, considering the compressor was off for two days).

At this point I was ecstatic that the problem took all of about 10 seconds to solve but going crazy trying to figure out what caused it. I was moving the wires around, yanking on them rubbing them on the starting capacitor trying to provoke something to no avail.

Any idea what happened? I closed everything up.  Obviously, I isolated the thermocouple from the starting capacitor, but I still wonder what caused this.  Since thermocouple readings are a voltage reference I was wondering if induction could slowly over time increase the voltage in the line?

Comment: Giving my question a negative rating without feedback isn't really all that productive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short yes, there are many ways that the internals of the refrigerator/freezer can degrade the measurement of the thermocouple. Currents can couple to the thermocouple and requisite circuitry capacitively, magnetically or through poor wiring and superimpose noise to the system. Read [this](https://www.newark.com/wcsstore/ExtendedSitesCatalogAssetStore/cms/asset/images/americas/common/mro/on_demand/nov2013/Making-Good-Thermocouple-Measurements-in-Noisy-Environments.pdf) if you are interested. But I would venture to guess that you either have a connection problem where the thermocouple attaches to the controller, a break in the leads or some insulation that is nicked off. Noise like this would certainly effect the accuracy, but a >100 degree error seems like a low frequency or dc signal component is making it in. This is because it is a refrigeration system with very slowly temperatures in normal operation, to skew the temperature like that it, the error should be coming from something at least as slow or slower than the system.

Comment: Or the 5 degreeC * 40 uV/degeeC = 200uV was overpowered by Efields or Hfields or or.

Comment: I would assume that any fields coupling to the thermocouple would be at a high enough frequency that any input circuitry would filter/average it out. But I suppose its possible, but in my opinion unlikely. But who knows, the hardware engineer could have just slacked off, or parts were removed in production.

Comment: I'm revisiting this post as it's been 11 months with no reoccurrence of the issue after simply isolating the thermocouple wiring from the starting capacitor.  At this point I'm convinced the issue was signal noise from the capacitor.